# request.url incorrect after ajax calls?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, authentication

I login to my Rails application using a login page which is reached either directly through a login link that uses the route

```
match 'ladmin/login' => 'ladmin#login'
```

or if I try to edit content.
In either case I get taken to the login page, which allows me to login and then returns me to the page I was trying to use or the app index page, but now as a logged in user.

**Most of the time this works totally ok, I get logged in and returns to my content edit page or to the links index page as expected (if I had just use the 'login' link iself).**

However I have been able to track down a bug whereby

**if I use either of my ajax links the `request.url` is remembered incorrectly going forward**

(to either toggle group shading or to toggle Summary/Details, then the next time (even if several clicks) that I try to login (assuming I am logged out initially) results in the blank page - though I am actually now logged in.  Interestingly I notice that when this happens, the url that I end up at in the browser address bar is always `localhost:3000/toggle_row_shading` which seems like a clue to the problem - it seems like the `request.url` is remembered incorrectly .

I `require digest/sha1` for authentication in the User model with various methods for authentication and password.

The relevant code would seem to be in my `LadminController`:

```
  def login
    session[:user_id] = nil 
    if request.post?
      user = User.authenticate(params[:username], params[:password])
      if user
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        session[:username] = user.username
        uri = session[:original_uri]
        session[:original_uri] = nil 
        redirect_to(uri || {:action => "index", :controller => :links})
      else
        flash.now[:notice] = "Invalid username/password combination"
      end 
    end 
  end
```

I can temporarily got around it with

```
  def login
    session[:user_id] = nil 
    if request.post?
      user = User.authenticate(params[:username], params[:password])
      if user
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        session[:username] = user.username
        redirect_to({:action => "index", :controller => :links})
      else
        flash.now[:notice] = "Invalid username/password combination"
      end 
    end 
  end
```

However this 'forgets' the page I have come from, e.g. an 'edit' link and just uses `links#index` to put me on after login which is not ideal.  It does get around the blank page problem though, as the steps to reproduce it now longer make it happen.

How can I have the login return me to the intended edit page and not give me the blank page?

btw my code for the ajax links is:

```
%a{href: '#', :data => {toggle_group_row_shading: 'toggle'}}
  click to toggle
```

Do I need an extra route perhaps as the app started at rails 2.3.8 ?

My routes include

```
match 'toggle_full_details' => 'links#toggle_full_details'
match 'toggle_row_shading' => 'links#toggle_row_shading'
get 'verify_link/:id', to: 'links#verify_link', as: :verify_link
get 'unverify_link/:id', to: 'links#unverify_link', as: :unverify_link
```

should I have them all as gets perhaps?

My application controller includes:

```
before_filter :authorize, :except => :login
```

and

```
def authorize
  unless User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
    session[:original_uri] = request.url #request.request_uri
    flash[:notice] = "Please Log In!"
    redirect_to :controller => 'ladmin', :action => 'login'
  end
end
```

Comment: Good catch!  yes, I added the code for that from application controller.

Comment: not sure but i think the problem is that an ajax request doesn't change uri and hence somehow your uri is nil and so blank page is showing up. can you inspect it by debugger what uri value you have in your controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this happen to me before. The problem I found was that for AJAX requests, the `session[:original_uri]` is still getting stored and... is bad. Basically, it's storing a uri for an ajax request which doesn't display very well after logging in. The code I ended up with is something like:

```
if request.get? && !request.xhr?
  session[:original_uri] = request.url
end
```

This way we're not storing into the `session[:original_uri]` things that shouldn't be redirected to after logging in. You may find other things in your app to add to this conditional. For example, I had some download links that would render a `send_file`, but those were no good for storing for next login either.